# remove duplicates , but have problems with delete column with "-"

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

i have this input file..
I need to remove the duplicated rows in column 13 but I have a problem with the data that contains a **"-"** why does it not remove them

**input**

```
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RS|201908|RS|129220198
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|162230484
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|192863252
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RX|201907|RB|192863252
13220610|4|615906412|5|05502216092 |411|8|798|798|RB|201811|RB|13220610-4     
13219722|9|644118078|5|05502217789 |310|8|730|730|RS|201811|RS|13219722-9     
13219789|K|36062376|5|05202316950 |315|4|493|493|RS|201811|RS|13219789-K
13220015|7|70321801|5|05502623275 |310|1|359|359|RB|201811|RB|13220015-7 
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RX|201908|RX|48510787
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RS|201908|RS|129220198
13220610|4|615906412|5|05502216092 |411|8|798|798|RB|201811|RB|13220610-4
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|138290077
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|15568996K
13219789|K|36062376|5|05202316950 |310|4|493|493|RS|201811|RS|13219789-K
```

I need to remove the columns that have repeated column 13, but my code only removes the data from column 13 that does not have "-"

```
seen[$13]++; a[++count]=$0; key[count]=$13} END {for (i=1;i<=count;i++) if (seen[key[i]] == 1){print a[i] >>  (File".ok")}else{
print a[i] >>   (File".nok")}
```

**desired output**

```
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|162230484 
13219722|9|644118078|5|05502217789 |310|8|730|730|RS|201811|RS|13219722-9     
13220015|7|70321801|5|05502623275 |310|1|359|359|RB|201811|RB|13220015-7 
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RX|201908|RX|48510787
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RS|201908|RS|129220198
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|138290077
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|15568996K
```

appreciate your help

Comment: because only column 13 identifies duplicates .. if that column (13) is repeated I must delete both repeated records (without leaving any)

Comment: you're right . that primary key should not be there.. my error

Comment: output line 5 (== input line 10) probably also should be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sample input is accurate, some of your column 13 contain trailing whitespace. If you want to treat them as being the same value, you can trim it.

For example, before using column 13, you could do:

```
gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]$/,"",$13)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dual-pass approach will allow you to eliminate all records that have duplicated field 13, e.g.

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{seen[$13]++; next} seen[$13]>1 {next}1' file file
```

With trailing space in field 13 as noted by @jhnc, in order to match the duplicate non-whitespace, you will need to trim the trailing whitespace, e.g.

```
awk -F'|' '{sub(/[ ]+$/,"",$13)} FNR==NR{seen[$13]++; next} seen[$13]>1 {next}1' file file
```

**Output**

```
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|162230484
13219722|9|644118078|5|05502217789 |310|8|730|730|RS|201811|RS|13219722-9
13220015|7|70321801|5|05502623275 |310|1|359|359|RB|201811|RB|13220015-7
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RX|201908|RX|48510787
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|138290077
0|0|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|RB|201908|RB|15568996K
```

(**note:** the field 13 you show in your output `129220198` is duplicated in the input)

Comment: But how could I identify the duplicates of the rows that exceed a certain number of columns?

Comment: You simply compare against `NF` which is the *Number of Fields* in any one record, e.g. `NF > 12` will match all records with at least `13` fields.

Comment: Yeah i will try this .. but i have problems with the ‘End’ BEGIN{
FS=‘|’
OFS=‘|’
}
{
If(NF==14){
{seen[$13]++; a[++count]=$0; key[count]=$13} }
END {for (i=1;i<=count;i++) if (seen[key[i]] == 1){print a[i] >>  (File".ok")}else{
print a[i] >>   (File".nok")}
}else{
Print $0 >> (File".bad")}

Comment: You are missing a `{` after `for (i=1;i<=count;i++)` and you have an additional `{` after `If (NF==14)` (which has a capital `'I'` instead of `'i'`) It is hard to tell what may be typos or errors.

Comment: ok is to try to have an idea and to be able to have several cases of NF with their corresponding flow ... I will try to adapt what you helped me tomorrow and I will tell you how it goes :)